# Converting apache based rewrite rules to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

```
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have used automated conversion websites but for some reasons its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with such rewrite in root location:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  ...
}
```